# How to set an already created onClick method to an ImageView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have four buttons that ideally will only be clickable after the previous button has been clicked. Apparently if you set an onClick method, even if `android:setEnabled = false` and `android:setClickable = false` I can still click them. So I removed the onClick from the ImageView's XMLs and now I need help on how to assign it to each subsequent ImageView.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/sq2"
        android:background="@color/postFocus"
        android:onClick="imagePress"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/sq4"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4">
        <requestFocus />
    </ImageView>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq4"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq2"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq3"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq1"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@color/preFocus"
        android:id="@id/sq1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/sq3"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/sq2"
        android:nextFocusRight="@id/sq4">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<Integer> viewArray;
    //public boolean flag;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //flag = true;

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        final int childcount = rl.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++){

            viewArray.add(rl.getChildAt(i).getId());

        }

    }


    public void clickableChange(){

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        final int childcount = rl.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childcount - 1; i++){
             ImageView square = (ImageView) findViewById(viewArray.get(i));
             ImageView nextSquare = (ImageView) findViewById(viewArray.get(i+1));

            if (square.getDrawable() != null){
                nextSquare.setClickable(true);
                //Code Here!!!
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), square.getId() + "is now clickable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void imagePress(View test){
        int id = test.getId();
        ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(id);

        final int pictureId = id;
//        final int nextId = viewArray.get(id + 1);


        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageView empty = (ImageView) findViewById(pictureId);

                if (empty.getDrawable() == null){

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());


                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem selection) {
                        ImageView thisThing = (ImageView) findViewById(pictureId);
                        Drawable icon = selection.getIcon();

                        thisThing.setImageDrawable(icon);
                        clickableChange();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image is already set!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I set an already created onClick method to an ImageView programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
nextSquare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        // call the method you want
     }
});
```

Comment: I realized this maybe an hour after I posted this. It worked perfectly. But even though I sorted it myself I'll still give the points. Thanks for your help!